# Getting Error "KeyError" when extracting JSON values

Tags: python, json, keyvaluepair

I am successful in extracting the response from a JSON. However, I am unable to list all or extract what I need on the key and its pair

Below is my code:

```
import requests

response = requests.get("https://www.woolworths.com.au/apis/ui/Product/Specials/half-price?GroupID=948&isMobile=false&pageNumber=1&pageSize=36&richRelevanceId=SP_948&sortType=Personalised")

data = response.json()
```

I tried to do `data['Stockcode']`

but no  luck or I use `data['Product']`

It says:

```
>>> data['Product']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'Product'
>>> data['Products']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'Products'
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
>>> data['Items'][0]['Products']
```

Print data and see its data structure How its constructed then you can extract values as per your need